# Can't use spring sessions on Vaadin

Tags: spring-boot, session, vaadin, spring-session, vaadin14

If i add spring-session jdbc to my vaadin-spring-boot-application the application is very slow and does a full page reload after a few seconds. Everything else looks like it is working normally.

I do not notice the problem and I have been researching on this issue for a few days and got this [Github issue](https://github.com/vaadin/spring/issues/340) and [Vaadin microservices configuration](https://vaadin.com/blog/microservices-high-availability) But in these, I did not find a suitable solution to solve this problem, Any one can give me an true example to implemention **Spring sessions on Vaadin**?

Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Session replication schemes like `spring-session` assumes that the session is relatively small and that the content isn't sensitive to concurrent modification from multiple request threads. Neither of those assumptions hold true for a typical Vaadin application.

The first problem is that there's typically between 100KB and 10MB of data in the session that needs to be fetched from the database, deserialized, updated and then again serialized and stored in the database for each request. The second problem is that Vaadin stores a lock instance in the session and uses that to ensure there aren't multiple request threads using the same session concurrently.

To serialize a session to persistent storage, you thus need to ensure your load balancer uses sticky sessions and typically also use a high performance solution such as Hazelcast rather than just deserializing and serializing individually for each request.

For more details, you can have a look at these two posts:

- https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/hazelcast
- https://vaadin.com/blog/session-replication-in-the-world-of-vaadin